# Zope mapping URLs to views

Tags: python, zope

I am debugging large Zope application, and no experience with Zope Framework. I am trying to find code which is called requests.

All I know, that pages are generated by calls to instances of `Products.Five.browser.BrowserView`, but how to know which of them will be called? How zope maps URLs to views?

Comment: Traversal over an object tree, then looking up the view for the current object.

Comment: http://docs.zope.org/zope_secrets/request.html

Comment: As Martijn says, Zope does graph traversal (left-to-right) through the pieces of your URL.  What your question does not specify is how you, specifically, want to map URLs to views?  Views always have a context -- usually content, or the site, or something else.  What is the context/content on which your view is to be applied?  Do you really want something like routes in other web frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you want to know which View is called for a specific URL. In all instances of Zope applications I ever came across there are files named `configure.zcml` in the main folder of the application, in which you can start to look how the parts are fitted together.

If it is not apparent *where* to look for, you can start in one of the following places:

- in the instance location (`INSTANCE_HOME`) of your application, there is possibly a `etc/package-includes/` path, with one ore more .zcml-files in it ("config slugs") which list packages where zope looks for `configure.zcml`-files
- all directories below `$INSTANCE_HOME/Products` are searched for `configure.zcml`-files

There you look for sections like this::

```
<browser:page
    for="*"
    permission="zope2.View"
    name="this_is_an_url_name"
    class="package_name.module_name.ClassName"
    />
```

which maps an URL to an View.

Also, heads up :-) Zope has some learning curve, but it *is* powerful.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow `pss` was skipping zcml files by default. Plain `grep -r` helped.